# JavaScript: get custom button's text value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that is defined as follows :

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen26" class=" x-btn-text">button text here</button>
```

And I'm trying to grab it based on the text value. Hhowever, none of its attributes contain the text value. It's generated in a pretty custom way by the look of it.

Does anyone know of a way to find this value programmatically, besides just going through the HTML text? Other than attributes?

Forgot one other thing, the id for this button changes regularly and using jQuery to grab it results in breaking the page for some reason. If you need any background on why I need this, let me know.

This is the JavaScript I am trying to grab it with:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) 
{
var elem = all[i];
if(elem.getAttribute("id") == 'ext-gen26'){
    if(elem.attributes != null){
        for (var x = 0; x < elem.attributes.length; x++) {
            var attrib = elem.attributes[x];
            alert(attrib.name + " = " + attrib.value);  
        }
    }
}
};
```

It only comes back with the three attributes that are defined in the code.

`innerHTML`, `text`, and `textContent` - all come back as `null`.

Comment: That "text value" *is* the "html text"; that's all you can do to get it because that's the only place it exists in the DOM. *edit* wait; do you want to get the text from the button, or do you want to *find* the button based on its contents?  The title of your question and the wording of that first sentence sort-of conflict; "get custom button's text value" versus "I'm trying to grab it based on the text value."  Those mean different things.

Comment: Are you tring to find a button with the content 'button text here', and do something with that ?

Comment: @Pointy - Yes ultimately I'm trying to get a hook on the button itself, based on that text value that is between the tags. 'textContent' and innerHTML both come back as null. :(

Comment: @hacket if those are null then you don't have a reference to the button. You should probably post some of the JavaScript code in question.

Comment: @Allan - yes, this is my end goal. The ID for this field is dynamic, and if I use jQuery to grab it, it causes the rest of the page to not function correctly.

Comment: I have posted the JS I am using.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're trying to locate the button entirely by its text content, I'd grab a list of all buttons and loop through them to find this one:

```
function findButtonbyTextContent(text) {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  for (var i=0, l=buttons.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].firstChild.nodeValue == text)
      return buttons[i];
  }  
}
```

Of course, if the content of this button changes even a little your code will need to be updated.

Comment: This is close to what I ultimately ended up implementing. There simply was no way to select that button using any attribute.

Answer (score 43):

You can do that through the `textContent`/`innerText` properties (browser-dependant). Here's an example that will work no matter which property the browser uses:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('ext-gen26');
var txt = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
alert(txt);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/EcMRT/

You could also do it using jQuery:

```
alert($('#ext-gen26').text());
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however, I updated to reflect that the ID and jquery do not work for my situation.

Answer (score 4):

One liner for finding a button based on it's text.

```
const findButtonByText = text => 
  [...document.querySelectorAll('button')]
    .find(btn => btn.textContent.includes(text))
```