# Copying a home address to the users clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

I have an address written over multiple lines with paragraphs:

```
<p>Address line 1</p>
<p>Address line 2</p>
<p>Address line 3</p>
<p>County</p>
<p>Post code</p>
```

I want to make it possible for a user to click on any of the paragraphs to copy the text to their clipboard. If possible I would also like a small "click to copy" message to appear when hovering over the address.

I have tried wrapping the paragraphs in a button that calls a function when clicked.

```
<button onclick="copyText()">
    <p class="copy">Address line 1</p>
    <p class="copy">Address line 2</p>
    <p class="copy">Address line 3</p>
    <p class="copy">County</p>
    <p class="copy">Post code</p>
</button>
```

The function in JS is written as:

```
function copyText(){
    var copyText = document.getElementsByClass("copy");
    let text = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < copyText.length; i++) {
        text += copyText[i] + "<br>";
    }


    // Select the text field
    text.select();
    text.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

    // Copy the text inside the text field
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value);

    // Alert the copied text
    alert("Copied the text: " + text.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` can't go inside `<button>` but `<span>` is valid. You can read up more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button)

Also, `getElementsByClass()` is invalid. It should be `getElementsByClassName()`. The [console in your browser's developer tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should be telling you that.

To get a message to show on hover, you can [make use of a the title attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456543/make-text-show-up-on-hover-over-button).

So, change your HTML to something like:

```
<button title="click me to copy" onclick="copyText()">
    <span class="copy">Address line 1</span>
    <span class="copy">Address line 2</span>
    <span class="copy">Address line 3</span>
    <span class="copy">County</span>
    <span class="copy">Post code</span>
</button>
```

And then use css to style the spans as `display: block;` if you want each element of the address to be on a new line.

And change this line in your JS:

```
var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("copy");
```

Then, `copyText` does not have the text of the button itself. It's contained in the `contentText` or `innerText` property. You can read up more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351658/javascript-get-custom-buttons-text-value)

```
for (let i = 0; i < copyText.length; i++) {
     text += copyText[i].contentText + "<br>";
}
```

It's unclear what you're trying to do here but it's invalid because `text` is a variable, not a thing you can called functions like `.select()` on.

```
// Select the text field
text.select();
text.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
```

I just commented the above out because you don't need it to meet your described objective.

To get the content you're looking for, simply use `text` and not `text.value`. So, for example:

```
alert("Copied the text: " + text);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty solution I suggest you wrap in DIV element instead of BUTTON element. You can then pass "this" to copyText function to pass DIV context where you can simply pull innerText property of DIV.
For eg.

```
function copyText(theDiv){
  alert(.innerText)
}
```

For your hover message I suggest you simply add TITLE attribute as per below.

```
<div onclick="copyText(this)" title="click to copy">
   <p title="click to copy">Address line 1</p>
   <p title="click to copy">Address line 2</p>
   <p title="click to copy">Address line 3</p>
   <p title="click to copy">County</p>
   <p title="click to copy">Post code</p>
```

Hope helps